# How to use properties file is its being excluded while exporting the JAR

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have faced this as an interview question on Spring-boot.

The question was like -- If i have a Spring Boot application developed , while exporting it as a JAR file , i excluded properties file and extracted the JAR out of my project , when importing this JAR into other project , and placing that properties file externally in some other path.

How will the classes of the JAR file imported will read the properties file placed at a new location.?

I did some search on the above scenario , am not sure what i read is correct or not , but in my opinion it should be done using externalized configuration by @configurationproperties annotation. That's what i found , but it can be totally wrong.

Please suggest me the answer to this , and if my assumption is correct then also how will i achieve this . Please explain.?

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively use the externalized configuration mode, which can be enabled by specifiying `--spring.config.location` when lauching the JAR file.

Example from the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) :

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```